# ArcGIS 10.1 crashes during connection with ArcSDE 10.2 in Oracle 11g database

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-spatial

I have been having this issues of ArcGIS (ArcMap and ArcCatalog) crashing on me every time I try to connect to the databases. I have updated both client and server patches for Oracle as suggested by ESRI tech support but nothing has changed. I cannot even click on the Properties without getting ArcGIS to crash. I am using Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 64-bit OS. Has anyone encountered this and have solution for it?

Comment: What SP of Desktop 10.1?  In general, best practice is to update the clients *before* the servers.  Crashes are due to external DLL failure, so it would be necessary to specify which exact Oracle release the server is at, and which client you are using.

Comment: Thank you so much Vince. It's SP1. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Probably not.  Certainly not without ***exact*** Oracle version information.  Esri Tech Support is your best chance to find a solution.  GIS SE is not supposed to be a replacement for GIS vendor tech support.

Answer (score 1):

Please upgrade your ArcMap / ArcGIS for Desktop to 10.2. ESRI has always, since version 8.0, the first release of ArcGIS, came out 17 years ago, clearly stated you need to upgrade your clients before you upgrade your geodatabase.

Look at it from another side, you don't expect Office '95 to be able to open your Office 365 documents, do you? So why do you expect ArcMap 10.1 to be able to access a 10.2 database?

Comment: In this particular case, 10.2 was originally going to be 10.1.2, so there is more compatibility.  If the Oracle DLLs are fataling 10.1, they might fatal 10.2.  Using 10.2.2 with the most recent Oracle patches is worth a try, but I expect it's not the ArcGIS, and instead something else.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround for this problem is to perform the appropriate Oracle Critical Patch Update for your ArcGIS version https://support.esri.com/download/2143